# can't get C++ sfml to check if text is blue

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to write a code that checks if the color of answer2 is blue to know if the user got the wrong answer or not, but the compiler isn't allowing it in SFML

```
if (!next)
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(test))
        {
            switch (test.type)
            {
            case Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case Event::KeyPressed:
                if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Num1))
                {
                    answer1.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
                    answer2.setFillColor(Color::Black);
                }

                if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Num2))
                {
                    answer2.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
                    answer1.setFillColor(Color::Black);
                }
                if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Enter))
                {
                    next = true;
                    running = true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    next = false;
    if (!next)
    {
        answer2.getFillColor = answer;
        if (answer == "Blue")
        {
            question.setString("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            question.setString("Wrong");
        }
    }
```

This is the error message I got from the compiler

> c:\users\just a guy\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\francais project\francais project\francais project.cpp(90): error C2659: '=': function as left operand

Comment: Store the answer status in a variable instead of trying to deduce it from how you're displaying something. For instance in an `enum Status { Indeterminate, Wrong, Correct};`

Comment: not related but `next = false; if (!next){` that's just going to be always true.

Comment: Regarding the error: `answer2.getFillColor` is a function, and you're trying to assign the value of `answer` to it. You can't do that.

Comment: how do I store the color of the text into the enum

Comment: I will fix the next problem don't worry. I just need to know who store the color of a text into a variable.

Comment: @Juan You don't store the colour of the text; you store the correctness of the answer and then you set the colour of the text based on that. That is, let the information flow from facts to visualisation instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answer2.getFillColor = answer;`

is wrong. `getFillColor` is a function and you can't assign any value to that. If you want the *value* of that function use `answer2.getFillColor()` and let it be on the right side of the expression.

`answer = answer2.getFillColor();`

assuming your code, `answer` is a `std::string`. But you can't convert a `sf::Color` to `std::string`. Instead let `answer` be a `sf::Color`. This way you can actually check if it is blue by comparing to `sf::Color::Blue`:

```
sf::Color answer;
//...
answer = answer2.getFillColor();
if (answer == sf::Color::Blue)
{
    question.setString("Correct");
}
else
{
    question.setString("Wrong");
}
```

Comment: I replaced my dll files just because my debug version was saying sfml-graphics-2-d.dll not found but now I am getting entry point not found in the compiler and so my code doesn't work anymore

Comment: you need all `.dll` files at your project.

Comment: I have all the .dll files I copied them again just to be sure and the entry point not found says ?setFillColor@Text@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@z could not be located in the dynamic link library and then points to my .exe file in my debug

Comment: I copied my .dll from my previous project with Lynda.com it works now thank you for staying with me to fix my code. how do I mark you're answer as the answer on my post